# How to keep leading zeroes when pasting into excel file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Is there any way to not change the formatting of the column when pasting a value into the column?**

---

I've found a ton of workarounds that are "after the fact"-fixes. Ones where you paste it in, format the columns as text and then add the leading zeroes afterwards etc. **This is not what I want.**

For context I want to be able to post GTIN-numbers into a excel document and later import it on a website. GTIN can be 8,12,13 or 14 numbers long (no way to be sure which one it is).

A number that I would want to paste is **02327718200002**, but every time I do that it looks like this:

[image: What happens when I post 02327718200002 into a text-formatted column.]

What happens is that the column that was formatted as text before the paste turns into a "general"-formatted column and is read as a number. This leads to the complete removal of the leading 0. So even if I right click my column and format it as text...the leading 0 is gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261787/how-to-prevent-automatic-truncation-of-leading-zeros-in-excel-cell

Comment: Are you pasting from a cell to a cell or from an external source to a cell ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Well in this specific case it would be from an external source (website). But I would like to find some kind of solution where it wouldn't matter from where if possible.

Comment: @PankajJaju I specificly said that this was not what I wanted. Did you even read the thread?

Comment: I read that and pointed to the thread with a detailed discussion on the options available in Excel. Perhaps you should read that thread too.

Comment: @PankajJaju I read that thread and every answer before posting this question and it's all non-applicable to my specific problem.

Comment: @Danieboy - ZygD suggested a method which is very relevant to your question.

Comment: @PankajJaju I'm not doing an import from another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comments you have posted, and assuming you have already formatted the column to Text, you could use something like...

```
Sub PasteSpecial()

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False
End Sub
```

Hit Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor then paste this inside. Head back to the developer tab in excel, click on Macros and then highlight the macro (PasteSpecial). Click options, and you can then pick to add a shortcut. The code will then paste into the active cell on the visible sheet when you hit your chosen shortcut combo

When pasting into a cell within a column formatted to anything other than text, however, it will take on the default "General" type.

*NB. Use this if you want to make a Custom shortcut or if you also want to do additional manipulation. There is also a shortcut build it CTRL + ALT + V that will paste special too. Personally I find the built in shortcut clumsy to use*

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a beginner now but...where exactly do I put this code? I would assume it's in the Alt+F11 menu somewhere.

Comment: Took me a while to find the developer tab in my Swedish version...but the solution works!

Comment: It appears that sometimes it does paste in the "next" (to the right) column for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: @Danieboy Cant explain that. Could have something to do with your chosen keybind as the code shouldn't do that at all.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you could add another line in the macro to first set the cell's format to Text, before the existing line that does the pasting, couldn't you?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using classic ways of pasting, like CTRL + V, make sure your column is formatted as text first, then right click and select "Paste special". This will allow you to paste as text.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tested it - copy the number in the question and paste special > text and you'll find the zero has been removed

Comment: This did not work in any of the given alternatives (HTML, Unicode-text or text). EDIT: Changed my mind, if it's formatted as text when I paste as special - it does work.

Comment: Just make sure your entire column is formatted as text before pasting.

Comment: Which is *exactly* what OP doesn't want to do

Comment: @Danieboy Definelty works, you just need to format the col first

Comment: I'm just curious if there's a way to do this...the "ctrl+v" way. If there's a script that I can put into the file that makes me able to use "ctrl+v" and still keep the correct format.

Comment: @CallumDA he doesnt want to manipulate the data. He wants to paste it as is, and it be exactly the same.

Comment: @Danieboy You could write a VBA macro that uses paste special, then create a custom keybind for it

Comment: @Takarii Now you're talking. But how would I go around doing something like that? Only written one VBA-script before.

Comment: If you want your column to be formatted as number you must use a custom format. In case of 14 digits number, you can format as "00000000000000", this way your  number will be displayed in 14 digits.

Comment: @PedroManuelVicenteMartins sadly I don't know if it's 8, 12, 13 or 14 numbers long. So I have to trust that they paste the correct length of the number with the correct amount of leading zeroes.

Comment: @Danieboy In this case you have two choices: 1) paste the numbers in a text file and then import it to Excel using VBA to see the length of each number and format accordingly. 2) Use the above solution using all column formatted as text before pasting anything.

Comment: I just tested this, if the cell is already formatted as Text before pasting, then the Paste Special > Text will preserve the leading zeroes. As a keyboard shortcut, CTRL-ALT-V does Paste Special.

Comment: @DanHenderson Thanks for the formatting tip. If formatting is kept as "Generic" no paste will ever work. When formatting is "Text", then Paste Special will work.

Answer (score 1):

Hello from the world of "I have an incredibly niche problem at the root of which lies this issue". I've looked far and wide for a solution, and hopefully now you won't have to.

If the style `mso-number-format: \@;` is applied to an HTML table's <td> element (containing the issuous characters), Excel will accept the numeric formatting override and display the content as desired, allowing a number to be displayed with a leading and/or trailing zero with a decimal point.

Example (fully working and may be pasted into Excel):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;mso-number-format: \@;">
        011001010110110001101111.011010000110010101101100
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great if you have the ability to coordinate with the owner of the system/tool that generates the source data from which you're copying!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has an easy solution now, to avoid automatic data conversion.

File, Data, Automatic data conversion, Remove leading zeros (uncheck)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).